# ASP.NET internal style appears from nowhere

Tags: css, asp.net, bundles

In every project, I find a strange internal style tag with bunch of code I didn't write...

[image: Internal style tag]

[image: Bunch of code]

[image: What I called]

I called only fontawesome and bootstrap via CDN...Is this style related with any of this? I am just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's not part of your website, but is rather injected through a browser plugin or a virus. Things to try:

- Does that same style load on other websites?
- Can you try the page in a different browser / incognito mode?

If so, disable all browser extensions and start enabling them again one-by-one until the styles show up again. That's the extension causing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Actually it only shows in the opera when the pop-up blocker is on. I have not paid attention so far, but today I saw it when I was doing debugging in the opera, and I was confused...Kenneth to the rescue! :) Thanks again mate, cheers!